# I cannot scrape the URL's of a news website

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have tried to collect the URl's of a website using Rvest but it seems the node/tag I am using ("node-title") does not contain the "href" of each link. However, if I use the same node/tag to collect the URL'S in the home page (I am trying to scrape the search section), it does work.

```
#Getting the dynamic URL using %d

url_espectador <- 'https://www.elespectador.com/search/proceso paz farc?page=%d'

#The original website is https://www.elespectador.com/search/proceso%20de%20paz?page=1

#Reading through the pages and collecting website elements
map_df(1:10, function(i) {
  pagina <- read_html(sprintf(url_espectador, i, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'))

  data.frame(link = str_trim(html_attr(html_nodes(pagina, ".node-title"), "href")),
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  }) -> titulos_espectador
```

What I get is NA for each string. Could someone help please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node-title` is for the parent element. You want the child `a` tag. So css selector

```
.node-title a
```

Note that this returns relative links so you may wish to add on the prefix.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)

url_espectador <- 'https://www.elespectador.com/search/proceso paz farc?page=%d'

#The original website is https://www.elespectador.com/search/proceso%20de%20paz?page=1

#Reading through the pages and collecting website elements
map_df(1:2, function(i) {
  pagina <- read_html(sprintf(url_espectador, i, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'))

  data.frame(link = paste0("https://www.elespectador.com",str_trim(html_attr(html_nodes(pagina, ".node-title a"), "href"))),
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}) -> titulos_espectador
```

Comment: was this what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks, @QHarr It worked perfectly. However, I am having troubles now collecting the content of each link. I am using 
content_espectador = lapply(titulos_espectador[ , 1], function(x) {read_html(x) %>% html_nodes(".node-body") %>% html_text %>% as.character}) It collects the article content but also with many other information (window.setContentCreated = \"2014-03-28T09:37:19-0500\";\n      window.setContentAuthor = \"EFE\";\n      window.setContentSection = \"Posconflicto\";\n) I do not know how to identify the tag that only retrieves the content

Comment: Make it clear what content you want from each page and how you want it output as well.

Comment: I one the article content (text) of each link. Since each link is a news, I one to collect the news content then. I would like to have it as a data frame. However, using the tag "node-body" I do scrape the news content of each link but along with many other data, numbers and information (not just the text of the news)